# how can I combine some lists into a big lists?

Tags: python

For example, I have two lists:

```
list1 = [4,6,7], 
list2 = [4,5,6]
```

how can I make it become?

```
[[4,6,7],[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: If it's python, the syntax is identical to what you have written.

Comment: This is a programming question, it's off topic here. Please ask questions about programming on StackOverflow https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is:

```py
list1 = [4,6,7]
list2 = [4,5,6]
combined = []
combined.append(list1)
combined.append(list2)
```

or

```py
x = [[list] for list in [list1, list2]]
```

Comment: or [list1] + [list2] (using the list concatenation operator "+")